# Base64 SHA1 encode with Java

Tags: java, base64, sha1

I am having some trouble obtaining a correct base64 encoded string using java.

This is the string that needs to be encoded: `" POST\nmBAcWORUK93FBOz6jsAuqw==\napplication/json\nFri, 26 Jul 2019 06:00:46 GMT\n/v1/api/userStationList"`

This is the secret key: `6680182547`

And my code:

```
public static String HmacSHA1Encrypt(String encryptText, String keySecret) throws Exception 
{ 
    byte[] data= keySecret.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(data, "HmacSHA1"); 
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1"); 
    mac.init(secretKey); 
    byte[] text = encryptText.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
    byte[] result = mac.doFinal(text); 
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(result);
}
```

Calling it:

```
String test = HmacSHA1Encrypt(" POST\nmBAcWORUK93FBOz6jsAuqw==\napplication/json\nFri, 26 Jul 2019 06:00:46 GMT\n/v1/api/userStationList", "6680182547");
```

I'm following some api docs and I should be getting `/2Np3q5h846q9cWEFUNtbL+G7H8=` but instead I get `4eiwJAFKXqrj4xvetzKUCodrNqI=`

Snip from api docs:
[image]

Any idea what is not correct?

Comment: The leading blank in the String is intended and exists also in the sample from the docs?

Comment: Yes as far as I can tell, added snip above.

Comment: could you provide the docs link?

Comment: Doesn't exist online, was only sent pdf but I uploaded it hre: https://smallpdf.com/result#r=482936050bf7370ee92c2ea769af379f&t=share-document

Comment: I think you misunderstood something from the PDF. It states that: `The calculation result of Content-MD5 of "{"userId":"1145611319416590338"}" in the example is: 
mBAcWORUK93FBOz6jsAuqw==` and on point 2.2.4, it is written POST\n**mBAcWORUK93FBOz6jsAuqw==** .... I mean, the "result" that should give is, indeed, written on the signature string. So i think that here, the problem, is that what's being passed to the method as the `encryptText` argument, is not what you should pass.

Comment: So I am getting the md5 string with `String md5 = getDigest("{\"userId\":\"1145611319416590338\"}");` which does give me `mBAcWORUK93FBOz6jsAuqw==` which then needs to be inserted into the HmacSHA1Encrypt function so not sure what I am missing

Comment: @sd_dracula oh ok, now I get you

Comment: The way I am reading is that if you put the `" POST\nmBAcWORUK93FBOz6jsAuqw==\napplication/json\nFri, 26 Jul 2019
06:00:46 GMT\n/v1/api/userStationList"` string and the secret key in the HmacSHA1 method, you should get `/2Np3q5h846q9cWEFUNtbL+G7H8=` but not sure why it doesn't return that

Comment: I tried to find the error, but everything I tried so far outputs what you are saying. I really think that the problem is on the docs itself. Try to talk with the issuer. That's all I can tell you so far. Sorry.